# change string combination in rows df R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, rows

I need to modify certain values in rows. Here is the df I have:

```
      name            ref
4     SCF(SAF1)-AAH1  16677311
5     SCF(SAF1)-AAH1  17517885
12     ND(RSP5)-ACK1  15955809
13     ND(RSP5)-ACK1  17551511
49     ND(RSP5)-ALG6  17551511
52     ND(RSP5)-ALR1  11279208
```

Ineed to modify rows 12-13-49-52 as

```
RSP5-ACK1, 
RSP5-ALG6
```

and so on. So I need to remove ND and () without changing rows that not start with "ND" as 4-5.

Answer (score 0):

Read in data

```
dfr <- tibble::tribble(
        ~id,            ~name,    ~ref,
        4,     "SCF(SAF1)-AAH1",   "16677311",
        5 ,    "SCF(SAF1)-AAH1",   "17517885",
        12 ,    "ND(RSP5)-ACK1",   "15955809",
        13  ,   "ND(RSP5)-ACK1",   "17551511",
        49   ,  "ND(RSP5)-ALG6",   "17551511",
        52    , "ND(RSP5)-ALR1",   "11279208"
        )
```

Here is one way to do this:

```
dfr$name2 <- sub("ND\\(([^\\)]+?)\\)", "\\1", dfr$name, perl = TRUE)
dfr
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id name           ref      name2         
  <dbl> <chr>          <chr>    <chr>         
1     4 SCF(SAF1)-AAH1 16677311 SCF(SAF1)-AAH1
2     5 SCF(SAF1)-AAH1 17517885 SCF(SAF1)-AAH1
3    12 ND(RSP5)-ACK1  15955809 RSP5-ACK1     
4    13 ND(RSP5)-ACK1  17551511 RSP5-ACK1     
5    49 ND(RSP5)-ALG6  17551511 RSP5-ALG6     
6    52 ND(RSP5)-ALR1  11279208 RSP5-ALR1
```

You can also use the `sub` function instead of `gsub`, or change the Regex slightly, depending on the messiness in your `ND(something)-XYZ` values.